# Update matplotlib to matplotlib 1.3 on windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I want to try out the new .xkcd() function for matplotlib as shown here
http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/showcase/xkcd.html
but it is not working because I think it only works for matplotlib 1.3.  So I'm wondering how I would update to matplotlib 1.3.  I tried

```
easy_install matplotlib
```

but that did not seem to work.  Alternatively, if there is a way to use .xkcd() without updating, that would answer my question as well.  Also, I am using windows.

Comment: [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has matplotlib 1.3 for Windows.  Can't say I've tried that specific package, but others from that site have worked perfectly when I needed windows packages.

Comment: **Note**: The site I linked above is good for all sorts of python packages for windows, but as Steve Barnes points out in his answer, matplotlib offers *official* packages for windows, which should of course be preferred.

Comment: Thanks I have used that site before but I had forgotten about it

Comment: Better yet it is a different page on the same site as the example that is given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [this](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html) page pick the version of python that you are using, download the exe and run it.